# Invalid resource manager ID in primary checkpoint record

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I've update my Airbyte image from `0.35.2-alpha` to `0.35.37-alpha`.
[running in kubernetes]

When the system rolled out the db pod wouldn't terminate and I [a terrible mistake] deleted the pod.
When it came back up, I get an error -

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

2022-02-24 20:19:44.065 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027) 10.3.1 20211027, 64-bit
2022-02-24 20:19:44.065 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-02-24 20:19:44.065 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-02-24 20:19:44.071 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-02-24 20:19:44.079 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-02-24 20:12:55 UTC
2022-02-24 20:19:44.079 UTC [21] LOG:  invalid resource manager ID in primary checkpoint record
2022-02-24 20:19:44.079 UTC [21] PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
2022-02-24 20:19:44.530 UTC [1] LOG:  startup process (PID 21) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2022-02-24 20:19:44.530 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2022-02-24 20:19:44.566 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Pretty sure the WAL file is corrupted, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: That's what you have a backup for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Warning* - there is a potential for data loss

This is a test system, so I wasn't concerned with keeping the latest transactions, and had no backup.

First I overrode the container command to keep the container running but not try to start postgres.

```
...
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: airbyte-db-container
          image: airbyte/db
          command: ["sh"]
          args: ["-c", "while true; do echo $(date -u) >> /tmp/run.log; sleep 5; done"]
...
```

And spawned a shell on the pod -

```
kubectl exec -it -n airbyte airbyte-db-xxxx -- sh
```

Run `pg_reset_wal`

```
# dry-run first
pg_resetwal --dry-run /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
```

Success!

```
pg_resetwal /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
Write-ahead log reset
```

Then removed the temp command in the container, and postgres started up correctly!

Comment: `pg_resetwal` sometimes can be risky. Once it broke some of the transactions in my database and it seems that the database was fully functional but it was not. So create backups before running this command.